# Can cache manifest be used as a "firewall" for a page or a web app?

Tags: security, html, cache-manifest

When playing with [HTML5 cache manifests](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#manifests), I eventually learned, that listing `/` under the `NETWORK` segment effectively *rejects all off-domain* connections, like CDN links for example.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
/
```

Similarly, using `*` wildcard *allows all* resources:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
*
```

Empty `NETWORK` segment *rejects all* connections anywhere:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
```

Such network policy rules would be neat. Especially the `/` domain-lock looks to be a sweet little roadblock for [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Do the browser implementations differ in this aspect or is it by the book and safe to use this as a basic level network filter, an another layer of a web app's "firewall"?